# visual studio no guarda los cambios en el frontend

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio

visual studio no actualiza los cambios, pero solo me pasa en el frontend, cuando cambio reglas css o archivos de javaScript

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! De tu pregunta, no se entiende nada. podes darnos un ejemplo o explicar mejor que te pasa? si no, es muy probable que se cierre

Comment: Me gustaría poder ayudarte pero no tengo idea de qué está ocacionando el problema, ya que no subes nada de código. Te recomiendo que leas cómo formular preguntas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Al lado de botón de ejecución hay uno de "Refrescar (Refresh)" si le das clic al menu desplegable te dará algunas opciones para que se refresquen los archivos.

[image: Ejemplo Actualización Automática]

Ahora si al hacer esto aún así no te refresca los archivos puedes presionar el atajo Ctrl + F5 en el navegador lo que forzará a refrescar tus archivos.

Este es un problema de *caching*, que los navegadores hacen por defecto para no recargar archivos que "ya" tienen, no dices que estas usando exactamente pero si estas usando aspx puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css?v=<%=DateTime.Now%>" />
```

con esto cambiara la versión del archivo cada vez que haces F5 en el navegador haciendo que este piense que es un archivo nuevo y lo descargará, ojo con esto porque es usado en modo de desarrollo pero en producción no se utiliza esto ya que uno espera que el navegador haga el trabajo de *caching*

Espero te sirva esto saludos

Comment: De hecho las soluciones enviadas por LPZadkiel, son las más acertadas, solalmente puedo añadir que la más fácil de implementar es presionar CTRL+F5 en el navegador.